# How can I post user name and password from a Windows application to a web page to obtain user-specific content?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to fetch data from a webpage using C# and .NET. But page requires log in. HTML code of login page is something like this (page posts data to itself):

```
<form id="frm" action="./default.aspx" method="post">
<input id="userName" type="text">
<input id="password" type="password">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

I want to post relevant data from a windows application to this page. My C# code is as follows:

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("https://www.website.com");
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("userName","myUserName"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password","myPassword")
    });
    var result = await client.PostAsync("/default.aspx",content);
    var resultText = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(resultText);
}
```

When I manually fill the form and click the Send button user-specific page comes. But when I post the same data using my Windows application HTML code of the same login page comes, not the user specific page.

I am doing something wrong. But I couldn't figure out.

Comment: When you use a WebBrowser, the browser knows about all the fields of the Form you're filling in. The hidden ones included. It then passes them on when you submit the Form (use Fiddler to very this). When you use HttpClient, WebRequest etc, you have to pass on those fields yourself. This implies that you have to extract all the `INPUT` values in the Form (`HtmlDocument.Forms[0]`, possibly, but there might be more than one), + `__VIEWSTATE` and `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR`, if any, which will be included in the `FormUrlEncodedContent` as `KeyValuePair`s, to make sure the submission is accepted.

Comment: Yes. There are viewstate hidden fields in the form too.

Comment: I added them too. But didn't work. Also the webpage has only one form.

Comment: You don't even need to bother to know what's in there. Parse everything out of the Form's child elements and add them to the `FormUrlEncodedContent` collection. If it *doesn't work*, you need to post the code you're using now (especially the code that extracts the `INPUT` elements). Otherwise it's quite difficult for anyone to suggest something meaningful.

Comment: I have done it! Firstly I send a get request to the login page, then post the data to the same page. In the first request the page gave me cookie id. Then I rerequested with the same cookie id. I think the page does not accept post requests without cookie id.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this with Outlook web access (OWA) years ago. I created an application that hosted a web Browser control. I navigated to the login page. In code. Then using the DOM model I set the username and password before invoked the Login button. The next page would be OWA, in your case it would be the data page you want. Then use the DOM to scrape your data.